# Python aiogram и aiomysql (pending Ошибка)

Tags: python, aiogram, async-await, aiomysql

Вот такая проблема, при первом старте на 2 - 3 запрос на создание соединения к базе mysql выдает ошибку
код

```
@classmethod
async def connect(cls):
    print('AuthorizationDB 1')
    conn_inf = await cls.take_settings()
    print(conn_inf)
    print('AuthorizationDB 2')
    pool = False
    try:
        pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(host=conn_inf['host'],
                                          user=conn_inf['user'],
                                          password=conn_inf['password'],
                                          charset=conn_inf['charset'],
                                          cursorclass=aiomysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

    print('AuthorizationDB 3')
    return pool
```

Сама ошибка

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-32' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\PYTHON\NEW_BOT\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> wait_for=<_GatheringFuture pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000002E579982610>()]>>
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object Handler.notify at 0x000002E5799118C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PYTHON\NEW_BOT\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 126, in notify
    current_handler.reset(ctx_token)
ValueError: <Token var=<ContextVar name='current_handler' at 0x000002E578A93BD0> at 0x000002E579990940> was created in a different Context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения данной проблемы нужно создавать свои асинхронные задачи или выводить в отдельный поток, библиотека aiogram и aiomysql в какой то момент конфликтую.